# Is it okay to return a subclass from a class constructor that uses instancetype?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, constructor, return-type, instancetype

I have a class method in a category to construct a Cocoa collection in some way that the built-in initializers don't allow. Due to the limited initializer functionality, I have to use the mutable version of the collection to actually build it. Here's an example for `NS{Mutable}IndexSet`:

```
@implementation NSIndexSet (WSSNonContiguous)

+ (instancetype)WSSIndexSetFromMask:(NSUInteger)mask
{
    NSMutableIndexSet * set = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

    for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < (sizeof(NSUInteger) * 8); i++ ){
        if( mask & (1l << i) ){
            [set addIndex:i];
        }
    }

    return set;
}
```

My return type is sometimes a lie here -- there's always a *mutable* collection being returned, whether the user is requesting an immutable version or not.

Is it still appropriate to use `instancetype` in cases like this, or should I go with `id`? If I do use `instancetype`, should I also be explicitly re-creating the collection:

```
// Ick?
return [[self alloc] initWithIndexSet:set];
```

to make sure an immutable copy is returned when the call is `+[NSIndexSet WSSIndexSetFromMask:]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is okay:

```
NSIndexSet *set = [[NSIndexSet WSSIndexSetFromMask:0] addIndex:0];

No visible @interface for 'NSIndexSet' declares the selector 'addIndex:'
```

`instancetype` says to the sender, that you return a instance of the receivers type even it is a subtype. For the sender it is a NSIndexSet, because it is send to the class object of NSIndexSet.

An introspection that way, that someone looks to the return type and sees a subclass and takes any advantage out of this information, is malformed. The contract is build with the return type and this is in this case NSIndexSet.

Comment: «`instancetype` says to the sender, that you return a instance of the receivers type even it is a subtype.» I guess that's the heart of the issue. You think, then, that re-constructing the set to be immutable in the case of `[NSIndexSet WSSIndexSetFromMask:0];` is unnecessary, because treating the result as mutable is a programmer error?

Comment: 1. Yes, this is documented. 2. There is a second problem with it, but not in your code(!): Since many $collection in Cocoa has a subtype $mutableCollection the receiver(!) might change the content of the returned collection after returning the collection object without any chance of the sender to get notified about that. An NSSet can be an NSSet, too. Probably it was no good decision of Apple, to make mutable collections subclasses of collections, because it breaks with Liskov. In this case it is the task of the sender to copy the returned object. (Which is close to 0-costs, if immutable.)

Comment: 1. There is no leak of clarity: The return type *is* instancetype aka NSIndexSet. NSMutableIndexSet *is* an NSIndexSet by Liskov. 2. Donald Knuth.