# Using a va_list method without a count

Tags: objective-c, methods, variadic, variadic-functions

I'm writing a category on `NSArray` to add JavaScript array methods to `NSArray`. In JavaScript, the `splice()` method both adds/removes items to/from an array. But the number of objects added to the array may vary. So I used `va_list` to allow for a more flexible input of object values.

As it stands the method requires a count input value. How could I rewrite this without one?

**Interface**

```
@interface NSArray (JavaScriptArray)

- (NSArray *)splice:(NSUInteger)index remove:(NSUInteger)remove count:(NSUInteger)count arguments:(id)firstObject,...;

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
@implementation NSArray (JavaScriptArray)

- (NSArray *)splice:(NSUInteger)index remove:(NSUInteger)remove count:(NSUInteger)count arguments:(id)firstObject,...
{
    NSMutableArray *mSplice = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self];

    if (remove != 0) {
        NSUInteger removeIndex = index;

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < remove; i++) {
            [mSplice removeObjectAtIndex:removeIndex];
            removeIndex = removeIndex + 1;
        }
    }

    if (count != 0) {
        NSUInteger addIndex = index;

        id eachObject;
        va_list argumentList;
        if (firstObject) {
            [mSplice insertObject:firstObject atIndex:addIndex];
            addIndex = addIndex + 1;
            va_start(argumentList, firstObject);
            eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id);

            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                [mSplice insertObject:eachObject atIndex:addIndex];
                 addIndex = addIndex + 1;
            }

            va_end(argumentList);
        }

    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mSplice];
}

@end
```

**Calling the Method**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *fruit = @[@"Banana", @"Orange", @"Apple", @"Mango"];

    NSArray *fruitSplice = [fruit splice:2 remove:0 count:4 arguments:@"Lemon", @"Kiwi", @"Kiwi", @"Kiwi"];
    NSLog(@"fruitSplice %@", fruitSplice);
}

@end
```

**Debugger Window**

```
fruitSplice (
             Banana,
             Orange,
             Lemon,
             Kiwi,
             Kiwi,
             Kiwi,
             Kiwi,
             Apple,
             Mango
             )
```

Comment: You're updating the value of `removeIndex` but never using it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks! I've changed the line to: [mSplice removeObjectAtIndex:removeIndex];

Comment: Looking again, I'm not sure that's correct, though: when you remove an item, everything after it is shifted over. The original version should have worked; you actually need to get rid of the `removeIndex` variable entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `count` argument is no problem, because actually your "add" loop appears to be incorrect. After you've gotten the second item from the `va_list` with `eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id);`, you never get another object. The only reason your example works is that all the later items are the same: `@"Kiwi"`. If your test call was

```
NSArray *fruitSplice = [fruit splice:2 
                              remove:0 
                               count:4 
                           arguments:@"Lemon", @"Albatross", @"Kiwi", @"Kiwi"];
```

you'd see

```
fruitSplice (
             Banana,
             Orange,
             Lemon,
             Albatross,
             Albatross,
             Albatross,
             Albatross,
             Apple,
             Mango
             )
```

as output.

You need to redo your unpacking of the `va_list`, and you can keep your own counter while you're iterating it, but the catch is that there has to be a **sentinel value**: an value that can't possibly appear as a valid list value, that indicates you've come to the end. For object-type variadic arguments you would generally use `nil` as the sentinel.

When you're using a `va_list` you must have *either* a sentinel *or* a count. There's no other way for you to know when to stop popping arguments.

Your signature can become*:

```
- (NSArray *)KRSpliceAt:(NSUInteger)index 
          removingCount:(NSUInteger)remove 
          addingObjects:(id)firstObject, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

The `NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION` is strictly optional, but will make the compiler notify you if the method is called without a sentinel.

Then your adding loop changes:

```
// Insertion index starts at given splice point
NSUInteger addIndex = index;
// Initialize the va_list
va_list objs;
va_start(objs, firstObj);
// Start at the beginning
id nextObj = firstObj;
// Test for sentinel nil
while( nextObj ){
    [mSplice insertObject:nextObj atIndex:addIndex];
    // Update insertion point
    addIndex++;
    // Get next argument
    nextObj = va_arg(objs, id);
}
// Signal completion of list
va_end(objs);
```

---

*Methods you add to classes you don't own should always be prefixed. It's a bit annoying, but it's good practice to prevent a catastrophic clash if you should happen to pick the same name as another method.

Comment: Oh, and [you don't necessarily have to re-convert back to `NSArray` for the return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753478/is-it-okay-to-return-a-subclass-from-a-class-constructor-that-uses-instancetype).

Comment: Thanks Josh! I can't get over the fact that the method input looks like an array from 1999, but I'll get over it. This was a huge help. :]

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help.